# Compilation error LNK2019 in Qt with OpenSSL (Windows)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, openssl, lnk2019

I´m trying to compile a very simple proyect in Qt with OpenSSL, but it always show me a linker error, however works fine when I compile in Visual C++ 2010.

Code:

```
#include <openssl\sha.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    unsigned char in[] = "Hola";
    unsigned char out[33] = {0};

    SHA256(in,4,out);
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: símbolo externo _SHA256 sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función _main
```

I have installed:

- Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, 505 MB)
- OpenSSL-Win32 from a binary file (Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.1e, 16MB)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 (Express Edidition)

The .pro file from Qt is:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-11-29T23:21:36
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = prueba_openssl
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include
LIBS += -L"C:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib" -llibeay32
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Undefined reference means either library is not linked or found or library is linker but the function is not found.

In your case, it is looking for `_SHA256` which means function is undecorated and is using C.

It seems that you forget to use `extern "C"`. Either declare the required the function as follows:

```
extern "C"  unsigned char *SHA256(const unsigned char *d, size_t n,unsigned char *md);
```

Or put `extern "C"` under C++ macro. I hope this should solve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Using `extern "C"` did not resolve the problem.

I found a solution writing in Additional arguments :  "LIBS+=-LC:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib -llibeay32" "INCLUDE += C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include" "LIBPATH+=C:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib". (from Build Steps for your active project).

For some reason, the configuration of the .pro file is being ignored and has no effect on the project.

Thank you!